# Minus sign not showing in front of down-vote count in certain cases

Tags: bug, voting, moderator-election

It seems that the current election page - https://stackoverflow.com/election/7 -  has a bug where the minus sign will not be shown in front of the down-vote count if certain conditions are met. I can't determine exactly what causes it due to the limited number of candidates and vote distribution, but my hypotheses as to when this happens are as follows:

- if the down-vote and up-vote counts are comprised of the same number of digits

OR

- if the down-vote count is a three digit number.

At the moment of writing, the down-vote counts are only either two or three digit numbers, so it's hard to say what happens when they exceed 999.

Here are some examples

[image]
[image]

as opposed to:

[image]
[image]

Tested on Firefox 42.0.

As pointed out by Zizouz212 in the comments below, this applies to regular Stack Overflow posts as well (and presumably other SE sites); one such example can be found here: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122704#122704)

More posts that exhibit this behavior can be seen here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393323?minup=100&mindown=100 , as contributed by Deduplicator in the comments.

Comment: Repo'd, Chrome 46.0.2490.86. If we can get Ed, Undo, josilber, or Madara to 100 downvotes, we can find out if it's due to three digits, or due to the same number of digits. All the cases I saw, both numbers had three digits. (And I checked every candidate.)

Comment: Pretty sure this is by-design...

Comment: @Zizouz212 What would be the motivation behind selectively not showing the minus sign? It should be either always shown or always hidden.

Comment: @Kendra I don't think it's fair to award downvotes in moderator elections just to test bugs ;)

Comment: Not sure, but I understand that this isn't just for the election, and that this applies to all posts.

Comment: @szczurcio It wouldn't be- If they weren't reversible. ;)

Comment: Here's one such example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/4293417

Comment: @Kendra I said it half jokingly; they are indeed reversible, but we'd have to get _a few_ people to downvote then reverse the vote (or not, since they might wish to really downvote a candidate), so this gets more complex.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Good catch, I had a hard time finding an actual SO post with a three digit downvote count. Adding this to the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this may have something to do with spacing, regardless, they are already distinguishable with their location and colour in which they appear...

Comment: @Zizouz212 Indeed they are, it's not a significant issue, but there may very well be a more serious flaw related to/caused by whatever's causing this behavior, so I figured it would be good to investigate.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call it a bug, but rather just a simple annoyance to user experience. I wouldn't be toooo concerned about this.

Comment: I think it's intentional.  They don't want to introduce too much misalignment with the positive and negative value, and the fact that it's separated in this fashion *should* be indicative enough that one vote is positive and the other is negative.  Notice that it works fine for numbers < 100.

Comment: Here a query to find qualified posts: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393323?minup=100&mindown=100 The deleted one is the answer to [What real life bad habits has programming given you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you): "I now consider 256 to be a nice, round number. Occasionally I'm caught off-guard when non-programmers don't get that."

Comment: @szczurcio `What would be the motivation behind selectively not showing the minus sign?` Not showing it when there's not enough room (or at least when space is tight), and showing it when there's plenty of room, seems like an *entirely* reasonable motivation to me.

Comment: Ty221 has 256/288 but score shows "0", is this by-design too in the same vein of not showing negative score?

Comment: Also see [Election candidates with more than 100 downvotes are not showing the minus sign against the number of downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135584)